# Most efficient psql query to find count of records with date greater than date of target record

Tags: postgresql

given table changelogs

```
create table changelogs
(
    created_at      timestamp,
    user_action     varchar(255) default ''::character varying not null,
    id              serial
);
```

how can I most efficiently query for all records newer than the latest record with a given `user_action`

Something like this works:

```
select count(*)
from changelogs
where created_at > (select max(created_at)
                    from changelogs
                      WHERE user_action in ('target', 'target2')
)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please edit the question, not to comment.

Comment: I assume your data volume is huge(?). In that case, creating a partition table based on `"created_at"` might be helpful if it is possible. Also, creating an index on `"user_action"` column or creating a combined index on `"created_at, user_action"` columns might be helpful. It just depends on your data pattern. Could you please share index definition if there is any and also, execution plan for this query using `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`?

Answer (score 1):

Indexes on `(created_at)` and `(user_action, created_at)` should make the given query reasonably efficient, with the caveat that if you end up needing to count most of the table, nothing is going to be very efficient.

If that is not good enough, provide `EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for further ideas.